# Sigmund Freud related work to writer self empowerment by autobiography

Tags: reference-request, psychology, psychoanalysis

I am writing my thesis on **Quest of Feminine Identity**, and i came across the theory of Sigmund Freud that said that

> Feminist Writers use Autobiographies as means of self empowerment, exploration and fighting for issues relating to gender.

I have been reading up on Freud's various works, but the problem i am facing is the vast quantity of material that is available on Freud's work. Here i get lost as to which work of his specifically targets this theory.

Could anyone please guide me on where should i be looking in Freud's Work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this a quote? What is the context of this connection between Freud and autobiographies? Where did you find it?

Comment: It is a translated paraphrasing in l'ecriture autobiograhique.

Comment: "L'écriture autobiographique" is a publication?

Comment: I read it in the critical spectrum  of Kamala Das edited by Rajeshwar Mittapalli and Pier Paolo Piciucco. The article is called One woman's autobiography

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a very kindly interpretation of Freud. He considered both feminism and misogynistic machismo neuroses, the female and male versions of excessive sexual narcissism.

He was well-disposed toward female physicians and had many prominent female followers, including his own daughter.  But he saw the limitations on women in earlier periods as psychological accommodation, not oppression, and while escaping pointless limitations is a good thing, it seems obvious that he considered feminism *per se* wrong-headed.

It seems clear that since an aspect of the female gender role in his society was being spoken for, or having one's communication mediated through a male representative in most social situations outside one's own home, giving one's own account, especially in writing, was a common way for women to speak unmediated and directly to the society as a whole.

Some references might be available if you chase down http://www.narth.org/docs/1996papers/schoenwolf.html